# Which version of CEDET should be used with EMACS 24.4.1 for java development?

Tags: cedet, java

CEDET Version:  2.0
I have EMACS version

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2014-10-20 on KAEL
```

which comes with CEDET version

```
        Requested   File        Loaded
Package     Version     Version     Version
----------------------------------------------------------
cedet:      2.0     nil     ok
eieio:      1.4     nil     ok
semantic:       2.2     nil     ok
srecode:        1.2     nil     Not Loaded
ede:            1.2     nil     Not Loaded
```

Is this the best version to be using for java development?  I can find no mention of javap in the code yet it is mentioned often in the various documentation sources.

EDIT:

I am in the process if rewriting malabar-mode which relies heavily upon CEDET.  I am hoping to find the "correct" version so when malabar-mode is released, it will be based on the right CEDET.

Answer (score 1):

My [dev branch](https://github.com/alexott/cedet/tree/devel) of CEDET has some extensions for better work with Java, like basic Maven & Ant support, etc. But it wasn't updated for at least a year - I plan to spend some time over the Christmas to sync it with current HEAD...

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Is this the right one to base another package on?